# How to update N lines on screen with Python?

Tags: python, printing, tui, tqdm

I have spawned `N` processes and monitoring their statuses. So, I would like to print `N` lines on screen with changing statuses on each.

How to do this with python?

I don't wan't vizible re-prints. Is there any library like `tqdm` for such updates?

Comment: Did you have a look at Python's curses tutorial? https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a couple terminal escape codes:

```
def up(lines=1):
    clearline = '\033[2K' # clear a line
    upline = '\033[1A'    # Move cursor up a line
    for _ in range(lines):
        sys.stdout.write(upline)
        sys.stdout.write(clearline)
```

After this you can reprint your status lines. And then:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Here's a full working program demonstrating this:

```
import sys 
from time import sleep

def up(lines=1):
    clearline = '\033[2K' # clear a line
    upline = '\033[1A'    # Move cursor up a line
    for _ in range(lines):
        sys.stdout.write(upline)
        sys.stdout.write(clearline)

num_lines = 3
for i in range(10):
    for l in range(num_lines):
        sys.stdout.write('{} hello\n'.format(i*l+i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(0.5)
    up(num_lines)
```

Of course if you're making a full blown tui, you'll want to use something like curses or [urwid](http://urwid.org/)